# Dual Channel Memory configuration

Tags: memory, motherboard, dual-channel

I have a 880 Chipset socket AM3 motherboard with 4 RAM Slots. I am running Windows 7 32 bit. It’s clear from the manual that for dual channel memory operation, memory of same size, chip, brand and speed be used. The channels are Channel 0 (Slot 1 & 3) and Channel 1 (Slot 2 & 4).

I already have Corsair 2 GB x2 1333 Mhz in Channel 0. Now  if I set the controller to Unganged Mode in BIOS and add another Corsair but 4GB x2 (Either 1333 or 1600) in next channel, will such a configuration still support Dual Channel? So it’s 2 same sticks in first channel & another 2 same but different from first pair in second channel.

Comment: The answer is maybe... It really depends on the BIOS and the specific DIMMs you install. If the manual doesn't specifically state it, then you would have to test it. Honestly, I would give it a 50/50 chance of working. It seems to me when I tried this on my old Athlon X4 system I had to have 4 exact match DIMMs or it would just run in single channel mode.